# Intellij is not able to read any Maven related imports or classes

Tags: java, maven

I have a spring boot maven project. When I build the project with clean, verify, install command. It's a successful build. And later when I run tomcat, it gets successfully deployed as well locally. But it is not able to recognise java related imports and classes.
The whole project is painted red. I don't know what did I miss.  When I go to the maven dependencies, I see as if they are being locked. Sharing screenshots

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to invalidate caches and restart IntelliJ, it is available under _File_ in the menu.

Comment: done already. no effect

Comment: the reimport-button available in the maven menu? Have you tried that one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. After nothing recommended all over the internet did not work. I just kept wandering in settings.  Go to Prefernces--->Editor--->FileTypes

Check java has *.java included
Check Java Class has *.class included

Add them if not present. It will start working.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you didn't set up a proper Project SDK (Java JDK) in IntelliJ. You might want to have a look at that `File > Project Structure > Project > SDK`

Comment: I have actually. I am just not able to get what did i miss